# AttributeError: module 'opcode' has no attribute '__file__' for nuitka executable in a project including pandas and numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nuitka

I'm trying to compile a python project including numpy and pandas with nuitka but no matter how I compile it, I have an error when launching the final executable.
For compilation I use the next command :

```sh
python -m nuitka --standalone --follow-imports --plugin-enable=numpy --include-plugin-directory=.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas --include-plugin-directory=.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy --show-progress --show-scons newick2phylipmatrix.py
```

But when I try to launch the executable generated by the compilation I get the following message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mindsound/sandbox/distMatrix/newick2phylipmatrix.dist/newick2phylipmatrix.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/home/mindsound/sandbox/distMatrix/newick2phylipmatrix.dist/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module pandas>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/home/mindsound/sandbox/distMatrix/newick2phylipmatrix.dist/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 3, in <module pandas.compat.numpy>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/home/mindsound/sandbox/distMatrix/newick2phylipmatrix.dist/distutils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'opcode' has no attribute '__file__'
```

Currently without changing anything to the code, I manage to create a standalone with pyinstaller but I can't do it with nuitka but if it's possible I would like to use it to benefit from compilation optimization.

Do you have any idea where this problem comes from and whether it can be solved ?

Comment: Well even i am facing the same issue. And been looking for a solution. Yet to get any workout on the same. Have also posted the same on Nuitka site but waiting for a solution from their end too.

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally got the solution for the same. The distutils created / copied by the virtualenv while creation is different from the one in the pythons original distribution. One of the teammember at Nuitka helped me discover the same and helped me reach the solution. Well the option i discovered was to pick up the distutils from the Pythons lib folder and replace the existing distutils folder in the virtualenv folder created and the go ahead - compile the same. I believe strongly that the issue will go away for you too as it have gone away for mine. Now  will be looking to get in the proper solution for my complete project work.

Happy Compilation :)